# Formatting a 3x3 nd array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have 3 numpy arrays that I want to be in the shape of 3x3

I tried

```
x = numpy.arange(0, 19, 1)
y = numpy.arange(1960, 2017, 1)
z = numpy.arange(0, 1027, 1)

3D_array = numpy.array([x, y, z])
```

I had the expectation that I would be able to index this array as:

```
3D_array[0][0][0]
```

to return the position of 0 index in x, 0 index in y, and 0 index in z,
but the shape is actually (3,) and so when I try to index as above i get the error IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. and playing around I can see that the first slice shows all the xs, and the 2nd index is the place in the x array and the last one is out of bounds.

How can I shape this ndarray as I want?

Comment: Your 3 arrays have different sizes (shape).  They can't be stacked into one 2d array like that.  `np.array` is creating an object dtype array with 1 dimension.  Check the `dtype` as well as `shape.  What shape do you want the result to be? (3,3)? (19, 57, 1027)?

Comment: Do you know of a way I can accomplish what I'm trying to do then? I'm picturing a cube of data

Comment: I think you need to replace 3D_array = numpy.array([x, y, z]) with 3D_array = numpy.array([[x, y, z]])

Comment: `3D_array` is invalid in Python.

Comment: What value is supposed to be at `arr[i, j, k]`?  A tuple of (i,j,k)?  `i+j+k`? `0`?

Comment: I figured a way to get what I wanted in a way. I reshaped my z array to the shape of (x,y) now I can index z like I wanted and return the value I expect.

Comment: `np.zeros((19, 57, 1027), dtype=int)` is a 3d array of the right size, filled with 0s.

Comment: I would never have guessed that's what you wanted!

Comment: Ah, sorry for any confusion.. It was kind of hard to be general with my examples but put into words what I wanted. Maybe some context to the data would have helped. X is int value to represent countries, y is years, and z are gdp values of x country at y year

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but a suggestion based on your comments. You might find it more comfortable to use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) for this sort of spreadsheet-like indexing. Then you can name your indices and use more natural indexing.

For example, building on your use case:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([['Canada', 1985, 3.2],
                                    ['Iceland', 1985, 1.5],
                                    ['Canada', 1995, 3.8],
                                    ['Iceland', 1995, 2.5]],
                                   columns=['Country', 'Year', 'Data'],
                                   index=['Country', 'Year'])
>>> df.loc['Canada', 1985]
Data    3.2
Name: (Canada, 1985), dtype: float64
```